# This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future. error in android when using new material3 card

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How to set elevation for material3 card? I am using new material3 card and getting error

> This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.

Here is code ->

```kotlin
    @ExperimentalMaterial3Api
    @Composable
    fun ProfileCard(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(all = 16.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
            border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface),
            elevation = CardDefaults.outlinedCardElevation()
        ) {
    ...
        }
    }
```

I am not able to run app due to error caused by elevation how to set elevation?

Edit : Solved the issue by adding

```kotlin
elevation = CardDefaults.outlinedCardElevation(defaultElevation = 1.dp)
```

Why do we have to add border for **CardDefaults.outlinedCardElevation** why does't it show by default?

Comment: Its Material just because of material design principles

Answer (score 13):

If you find the same message in the future for another reason, one option could be to add in your **build.gradle** file, the following:

```
kotlinOptions {
    allWarningsAsErrors = false
    freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api'
    ]
}
```

In this way, after **Sync Project with Gradle Files** you will not see the warnings in your compose code.

Comment: This should be correct answer. And we don't need to add @ExperimentalMaterial3Api

Comment: Although this makes the message go away, you should still be aware of the implications. An API marked as experimental can change or be removed at any time and thus they want you to explicitly opt in to use it so that you know that it is experimental. Now, the thing that I don't understand is why JetBrains and Google push Compose and Material 3 so much when a lot of it is experimental. Maybe they should finish their stuff before they release half baked libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Update the implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3' to version '1.1.1'
i.e.,     **implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1'**
and  **Sync Project with Gradle Files**  the error will be gone.

Comment: Setting 1.1.1 version is not working for me :( Gradle sync is successfull but TopAppBar contines throwing the same error

Answer (score 5):

Try with the @OptIn annotation as below:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun WoofTopAppBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
...
}
```

Good luck!